# navigationItem.titleView won't update

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I am creating a button with two labels in it and setting that to the `self.navigationItem.titleView`.

This works the first time, but subsequent mutator calls don't update the `titleView`.

Adding the button as a property on the view with this bar and nilling it before resetting the `titleView` still doesn't update the bar.

Comment: Please post what code you've tried.